# Adding PDF Reading Capability to Android App

Tags: android, pdf

I have developed a simple android app which downloads PDFs and saves to external storage for user to open it in some PDF reader. But now I want my app to read the PDF on my own. I researched and checked that there are few libraries. One of them increases the size of app by 16 MB (That's huge for a 5 MB app). I don't know if this is the only and best way to achieve PDF reading capability. Then I read about PDFRendering API in Lollipop. Will it work on an app with MinSDK = 16? How?

The PDFs are simple with mostly 4-5 pages. I don't need many features which other PDF readers provide. Just basic scrolling and zoom features. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

> Will it work on an app with MinSDK = 16?

No. 16 < 21, the API level where limited PDF rendering was added to Android.

> What do you suggest?

Don't use PDF. Use HTML, then show that in a `WebView`.

If PDF is unavoidable, use one of the libraries.